# Software to help me replicate a hand drawn graph (example attached)

Tags: software-recommendation, chart-design

I'm trying to create a graph like this:

[image: Kili heights graphic]

I essentially want the x axis to function as a long timeline, on which I can plot the points at any given point manually. Some days might have more than one point (i.e. in this example Barranco Wall and Barranco Camp are both within Day 4).

Ideally I'd be able to add the initial data, and then manually adjust the position of the plotted points, add annotations, and add additional text/data below the days on the x axis.

I've tried using Excel and some browser-based graph designers but I can't do anything like this.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: AutoDraw is pretty cool https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/122297/45239

Answer (score 1):

My aproach would be, start with excell and do not draw the line, then  export it or copy it into a vector based program such as Inkscape https://inkscape.org/en/, there you add the line and edit the nodes as you need.

Actually all of that can be drawn on inkscape, but the data bellow the graph looks like a table, that is why i would start with an excell.

As you become more familiar with inkscape you can decide to do all the work there.

Inkscape is a free good option. If you want to pay some bucks you can try Corel Draw http://www.corel.com or Ilustrator http://www.adobe.com/.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any programming skills, the nest thing to go with would be www.highcharts.com

If you don't have any programming skills, then there is a variety of options:

1. Corel Draw
2. Sketch
3. Adobe Illustrator

All of those three options are very good, it simply comes to the point which one you'd like to buy and use later on in your career.